# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at app.js:2 with checkbox

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I created a checkbox in my html page :
`<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkbox">`
And I want to add the class "darkmode" when the checkbox is checked, so I did this in JavaScript :

```
var checkbox = document.querySelector('intput[name=checkbox]');
checkbox.addEventListener('change',function(){
if(this.checked){
    document.body.classList.add('darkmode');
}
else{
    document.body.classList.remove('darkmode');
}
});
```

But i get the error :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null     at app.js:2
Can someone help me ?

Comment: What is `intput`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of problems.

- You have a spelling error `inptput` should be `input`
- You should be looking for `type=checkbox` instead of `name=checkbox`
- `this.checkbox` probably doesn't work how you think it works. You more than likely want `checkbox.checked` as opposed to `this.checked`.

```js
var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]');
checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    document.body.classList.add('darkmode');
  } else {
    document.body.classList.remove('darkmode');
  }
});
```

```css
.darkmode {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
```